# Corrupted USB stick cannot be mounted or formatted

Tags: filesystems, usb-drive

I have a USB stick that I can't operate on no matter what.

```
lsblk -f
```

shows an empty line and no partitions

```
NAME        FSTYPE            LABEL       UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sdd
```

trying to access it using gparted, the key doesn't show up in the list of devices and I get this message in the terminal where I launch it:

```
Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system).  /dev/sdd has been opened read-only.
```

Is they key retrievable in any way?

EDIT 0

Attempting to write read write

```
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/sdd': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/sdd' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
```

EDIT 1

Dmesg output after plugging the stick in and out

```
[   61.206991] ntfs: driver 2.1.32 [Flags: R/W MODULE].
[   61.209903] ntfs: (device sdd): is_boot_sector_ntfs(): Invalid boot sector checksum.
[   61.209904] ntfs: (device sdd): read_ntfs_boot_sector(): Primary boot sector is invalid.
[   61.209906] ntfs: (device sdd): read_ntfs_boot_sector(): Mount option errors=recover not used. Aborting without trying to recover.
[   61.209907] ntfs: (device sdd): ntfs_fill_super(): Not an NTFS volume.
[  139.318870] fuse init (API version 7.25)
[  142.919271] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536
[  142.935413] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled
[ 1913.109712] usb 3-5: USB disconnect, device number 2
[10015.145651] usb 3-12.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[10015.449189] usb-storage 3-12.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[10015.453100] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-12.3:1.0
[10016.548609] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[10017.767817] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 61457664 512-byte logical blocks: (31.5 GB/29.3 GiB)
[10017.768085] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is on
[10017.768090] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[10017.768268] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[10017.768277] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[10017.772394] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[16021.938382] usb 3-12.3: USB disconnect, device number 6
[16025.472324] usb 3-12.3: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[16025.776233] usb-storage 3-12.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[16025.777524] scsi host6: usb-storage 3-12.3:1.0
[16026.891648] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Kingston DataTraveler 3.0 PMAP PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[16028.108523] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] 61457664 512-byte logical blocks: (31.5 GB/29.3 GiB)
[16028.108651] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is on
[16028.108653] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 80 00
[16028.108801] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] No Caching mode page found
[16028.108806] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Assuming drive cache: write through
[16028.112644] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue is with the usb device itself (but I could be wrong). Your filesystem on which the `/dev/sdd` device itself resides appears to be read only, so by implication nothing in that filesystem can opened for writing:

> ```
> Unable to open /dev/sdd read-write (Read-only file system)
> ```

Normally `/dev` is a read/write pseudo-filesystem, and can be remounted read/write. On some systems, however, it could be a simple subdirectory of `/`, and here you need to understand why the filesystem has been mounted read-only - usually this is a protection measure invoked if the filesystem driver encounters a consistency problem within the filesystem itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to re-partition and format a file system of a usb stick when it becomes corrupted.  Be aware this will basically lose any data that could have been on it.  But it is a quick and reliable way for making a usb stick usable again once it has been corrupted, and especially when Microsoft Windows Disk Manager or `diskpart` lets you down on it.

This is useful if for example you have done a `dd` on the usb stick where you have totally corrupted any partition/filesystem, or have copied a `.iso` file to the usbstick to make it bootable where the usb stick has gotten corrupted, and then Microsoft Windows is unable to work on it

- using `lsblk`, without the `-f` option, identify which block device the usb stick is seen as

  - `lsblk -o size,model,name,serial`
- for arguments sake let's say it identifies as `sdd`, and it may even have an `sdd1` partition, and if you also used the `-o fstype` with *lsblk* it shows as `ntfs`.
- `parted /dev/sdd`

  - `mklabel gpt`
  - `mkpart primary 0% 100%`
  - `quit`  *or exit, I don't remember which*
- now you can unplug your usb stick and insert it into a windows 7/8/10/11 system and do `disk manager` and be able to format it as NTFS if you desire that filesystem.
- To format the usb stick in linux it is just `mkfs.xfs /dev/sdd1` or `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdd1`, followed by:

  - `mkdir /myusbstick;  mount /dev/sdd1  /myusbstick`
- you could do mkfs.ntfs in linux, but my experience is that while it will subsequently work in linux it will not work in Windows10, so if you desire to use the usb stick between a windows and linux system then you need to format it as NTFS from within Microsoft Windows 10 (or 11).  If you only need to use the stick in linux, then there is no good reason to use NTFS. Use a linux supported file system such as XFS or EXT3 or EXT4.  I observe much faster write speed to a usbstick when using linux (RHEL-8.9) when it is XFS versus being formatted as NTFS from Windows-10.

Answer (score 0):

A few years ago I had a usb stick that there was a little button on it. From this button you could set the mode of the stick (read/write or read only). Okay, I know, too silly, but who knows.. Have you checked that?
Also, is there any possibility that the disk is encrypted? If you have an encrypted disk, when you plug it in, if you don't "unlock" it with your password, you won't be able to "see" the disk as a mounted device.

Comment: I should have mentioned it, the key has no switch and it was never encrypted. I think the file system is damaged somehow, but if I can't find a way to mount it rw I can't format it

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm how about ntfsfix? Assuming that your usb disk has a NTFS partition, you can try to ntfsfix the device. Like:

```
$ntfsfix -b /dev/xxx (for bad sectors) 
$ntfsfix -d /dev/xxx (for dirty flags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you `dd` it (eg: for installing something)? If so, just wipe it again with `dd`. If not, try:

1) Mounting it as ro (read-only): `mount /dev/sdd /mnt -o ro` and any other options. Then retrieve any data you can and wipe.

2) If it is just a corrupt fs, fsck can more often than not fix ext*fs systems. To run it, `fsck /dev/sdd`. For more info, `man fsck` is your friend.

Extra: `gparted /dev/sdd` will help you and give you a visual representation, too. GParted gives you a user-friendly GUI to work from. It's an invaluable tool for making life easier. Even many Windows admins I know use the GParted Live CD.

Comment: Issue is I can't mount it in any way. I believe the former filesystem was probably non ext* and so Fsck doesn't work (tried). I can't mount it in any way and gparted, which I love, is not showing it.

Comment: And I don't think I can dd it if it's not mounted. I think my only recourse left is to run chdsk from a Windows computer

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the bottom of your question regarding gparted. Have you tried mounting it with the `ro` flag? Also, check dmesg. Try `dmesg | grep sdd` and see what errors you get.

Comment: Re the other post, you must have it unmounted to dd an image to it.

Comment: But what image should I dd it with? One of a working file system of the same size? Or just dump whatever into it?

Comment: No, you needn't have an image. Just do `dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd` and, if you want a specific speed, add ` bs=16M` where 16 is [M]egs (bs = bytes per second). A higher number than the device's bandwidth shouldn't harm it, but I'd still err on the side of caution and check the manufacturer's specs or leave it to the default speed. It must not be mounted. Also **this will wipe your drive and all data permanently** so be careful.

Comment: I shall try, I don't mind deleting the content of the key.

It gives me an error:

Comment: It gives me the error: dd: failed to open '/dev/sdd': Read-only file system

Comment: Double-check it's not auto-mounted. `umount -f /dev/sdd` can forcibly umount it.